# Specialize a method form base class in a derived template class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism

I am having a bad time figuring out how should I make a template specialization. This time, unfortunately, google and SO couldn't help me.

For the base class:

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual ~base() = 0;

    virtual int getInt() { throw std::invalid_argument(std::string(typeid(*this).name()) + " can't return int"); }
};
base::~base() {}
```

and derived class:

```
template<class T>
class derived : public base
{
public:
    derived() {}
    derived(T value) { mValue = value; }

private:
    T mValue;
};
```

This code:

```
void proof(base* arg)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << arg->getInt();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    base* a = new derived<int>(23);
    base* b = new derived<std::string>("abc");

    proof(a);
    proof(b);

    delete a;
    delete b;

    return 0;
}
```

output, if wasn't already obvious:

```
class derived<int> can't return int

class derived<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > can't return int
```

How should I make a specialization of derived so getInt() would return the mValue ? Something like:

```
template<>
int derived<int>::getInt() { return mValue; }
```

This is not working.

To be more clear, I expect to pe output 23, when I call arg->getInt() and the exception I throw in base class when I call arg->getInt().
Can you give me a sample code ? Thank you.

Comment: That default constructor looks like a terrible idea! What does it *mean*?

Comment: I am trying to encapsulate some data types so I can make a vector of multiple data types. Note: the int was just an example, I do have another classes which don't encapsulate primite types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `derived` template does not have a `getInt()` method. You can't specialize what does not exist.

You have to specialize the entire template. Try this:

```
template<>
class derived<int> : public base
{
public:
    derived() {}
    derived(int value) { mValue = value; }
    int getInt() override { return mValue; } 
private:
    T mValue;
};
```

Comment: If this is the only solution, then I will have to make classes  over and over again for encapsulations. This was exactly what I want to not do: write same class 10 times but with different data types. Thank you for your help. Are you sure this the only way ?

Comment: Yes, that's how specialization works in C++. I'm sure there are other ways of designing a class hierarchy that makes use of specializations in a different manner. For example, you can create "template<class T> class not_really_derived : public base {};", specialize "not_really_derived<int>" for your getInt() only, and then have derived<T> subclass not_really_derived<T> instead of base, with no specialization.

Answer (score 1):

You could specialize the template for `int`:

```
template <> class derived<int> : public base
{
public:
    derived(int value) : mValue(value) {}

    int getInt() override { return mValue; }

private:
    int mValue;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. But isn't another solution so I can specialize only that function ?

Comment: @AndreiAndrey: You can always factor this pattern through intermediate auxiliary base classes so you don't have to repeat any common code. This is just one if the ingredients of the cake, you still have to bring all the others.

Comment: Going to find a chicken so I'll get eggs. Thanks.